# How does Langage.Haskell.TH.report work?

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

Unfortunately, many Template Haskell functions have absolutely no documentation at all. One such function is `report`. It takes a `Bool` and a `String`, and produces a compilation error with the specified string as the error message. Does anybody have any clue what the hell the `Bool` is for? As best as I can tell, either value does exactly the same thing...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the `Bool` is `True`, an error is reported; if it is `False`, a "warning" is reported, meaning that the template code will continue to run to collect more "warnings."

Comment: I had a feeling it would be something like that, but I wasn't sure which one was error and which one was warning. Regardless, it seems that compilation continues either way. (!) I would have expected reporting an error to halt compilation, but it doesn't appear to do so...

Comment: From the internal documentation: `Report an error (True) or warning (False) ...but carry on; use 'fail' to stop`. So, you have to take care of the "fail" step yourself, apparently; I find this to be a strange design decision.

Comment: Oh, you beat me to it. :-) Yes, strange indeed. From my testing, it seems that just calling `fail` is enough to halt compilation, giving the string as the error message, and the splice location as the source of the problem. Which is pretty much what I wanted...

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the source code, `report` calls `qReport`, which is a method of some class called `Quasi`. *This* method actually has some damned documentation - though only a tiny snippet. I quote:

> Report an error (`True`) or warning (`False`) ...but carry on; use `fail` to stop

So it seems to make my TH splice crash with an appropriate error message, I just need to call `fail` instead. Hopefully this information will be useful to anyone else trying to figure that out...